# Anonymous authentication not working on android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have enabled anonymous authentication as sign in method, and have everything working fine. except firebase authentication, I have required dependencies and firestore is also working fine in my app. But this anonymous authentication is not working.

Did anything and everything that might work, but didn't worked.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(submit.this, task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(submit.this, "Authentication Success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(submit.this, "Authentication Failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult result) {

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //Try to solve error here..
                }
            });
```